# Jquery SelectMenu breaks after closing SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, simplemodal, select-menu

When I close and reopen a [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) the [selectmenu](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=selectmenu%20jquery%20ui&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu&ei=tCUfT8SlCsG4tweCnNVP&usg=AFQjCNGFD3Ch7TbSzS2xhU4tIOJCA9w-_g&cad=rja) no longer works.

Anyone had any experiences with this or know how to fix it?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style>
        #simplemodal-overlay{background-color: #000;}
        #simplemodal-container { background-color:#333;border:8px solid#444;padding: 12px;color:white;}
        form { margin: 100px 0 0 0 }
        fieldset { border: 0; }
        label { display: block; }
        select { width: 200px; }
        .overflow ul { height: 200px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"></link>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="modal" style="display: none">
        <label>This dropdown works</label>
        <select>
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3">Third Option</option>
        </select>
        <p>Now hit esc key</p>
    </div>
    <a id="link" href="javascript:OpenModal('#modal', 200, 300)">Start By Clicking Here!</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.ericmmartin.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/simplemodal-login/js/jquery.simplemodal.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenModal(selector, h, w, reposition) {
            $(selector).modal({
                onClose: function (dialog) {
                    $.modal.close();
                    $('#link').html("Click me again");
                    $('#modal label').html("This dropdown doesn't work");                    
                }
            });
        }
        $(function () {
            $('select').selectmenu();
        });
    </script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can we see the code your using?

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your code via JsFiddle.net :-)

Comment: I couldn't figure out  how to build that in JsFiddle.. any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to modify either plugin. You just need to move the binding to the onShow callback. The following should do the trick:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenModal(selector, h, w, reposition) {
        $(selector).modal({
            onShow: function (dialog) {
                $('select', dialog.data[0]).selectmenu();
            },
            onClose: function (dialog) {
                $.modal.close();
                $('#link').html("Click me again");
                $('#modal label').html("This dropdown doesn't work");                    
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The option `persist: true` might also be required. If that does not work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simplemodal dialog plugin is causing this.

In short, when it closes, it executes this bit of code:

```
if (s.o.persist) {
  // insert the (possibly) modified data back into the DOM
  ph.replaceWith(s.d.data.removeClass('simplemodal-data').css('display', s.display));
}
else {
  // remove the current and insert the original,
  // unmodified data back into the DOM
  s.d.data.hide().remove();
  ph.replaceWith(s.d.orig);
}
```

The replaceWith removes the original DOM element and inserts the one that was copied for the creation of the dialog. Your selectmenu() is bound to the original object, which is now gone.  So while CSS is preserved (because simpleModal cloned the original), the event bindings are being blown away.

As an alternative to using the simplemodal plugin, you can consider using jquery-ui's dialog.  If you really don't want the title bar to display, simply add a `.ui-dialog-titlebar { display: none; }` to your css selector.

Here's a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/nfngy/

Comment: Any suggestions on how you would "fix it"

Comment: The best way would be to rework the extension completely, so that it's not using bad practices that kill your event bindings.

Comment: There has tobe an easier solution

Comment: I added an alternative to the original answer for you.  Either you can attempt to update the simplemodal javascript yourself (if you're not a strong javascript programmer, this might not be advisable), or you can just use jquery-ui's modal dialog.  If you want to hide the title bar, simply set it's class to display: none.